# Node.js how to use cheerio with phantomjs

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs, cheerio

I tried:

```
    phantom.casperPath = '/Volumes/SSD/admin/Desktop/parser/node_modules/casperjs';
    phantom.injectJs('/Volumes/SSD/admin/Desktop/parser/node_modules/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js');

    var cheerio = require('cheerio');
    var casper = require('casper').create(); 
    casper.start('http://google.com', function() {

     $ = cheerio.load(document.querySelector("body").innerHTML);
     console.log($('.logo-subtext'));

   });
```

the script displays an error: **the script displays an error**

Comment: Why not just inject jQuery?

Comment: @BenFortune, tnx )) i'm very stupid =D